# Is PropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged; same as protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin template like this. I think there are two ways to check if a property has changed.

- Adding PropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged;
- Overriding, calling base

If I want to do something when more than one property has changed is there any difference between these two ways of calling a method?

```
public class LinkLabel : Label
{
    public LinkLabel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += LinkLabel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        // Check property name and do action here
    }

    private void LinkLabel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Check property name and do action here
    }
}
```

For reference here is what I coded and I am wondering if that's a good solution:

```
public class LinkLabel : Label
{
    public LinkLabel()
    {
        SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Regular");
        SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty,   "LabelTextFontSize");
        SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty,  "LinkLabelColor");
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsImportantProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsImportant), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkLabel), false);

    public bool IsImportant
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsImportantProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsImportantProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName ||
            propertyName == IsImportantProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled) {
                if (this.IsImportant)
                    this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelImportantColor");
                else
                    this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelColor");
            }
            else
                this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty, "LinkLabelDisabledColor");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not the Xamarin expert, but this looks reasonable to me. Clearly more straight-forward than using the event in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the difference is that registering for the `PropertyChanged` event works from outside, overriding the protected(!) `OnPropertyChanged` method works only from within derived classes of Label.

So you would normally only create a new derived `LinkLabel` class if you want to change the behavior of the label. There, you'd override the OnPropertyChanged (if you need to).

If you want to get informed about a change in your main form, you would register the event directly there. No need to create a derived class.

Comment: So in this case, where I create the new type of label, am I correct in saying that the override would be an acceptable way to do it?  Note that I added the code I created to the question now to make things a bit more clear.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think the override is the correct approach here.